# Como usar java.String.format em Scala?

Tags: java, string, scala

Estou tentando usar o método `.format` de uma String. Mas se eu coloco %1, %2, etc. na string, a exceção java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException é lançada, apontando para um código Java confuso:

```
private void checkText(String s) {

    int idx;

    // If there are any '%' in the given string, we got a bad format
    // specifier.
    if ((idx = s.indexOf('%')) != -1) {
        char c = (idx > s.length() - 2 ? '%' : s.charAt(idx + 1));
        throw new UnknownFormatConversionException(String.valueOf(c));
    }
}
```

Concluo que o caractere `%` é proibido. Se é assim, o que eu deveria usar como argumentos a serem substituídos?

Eu uso [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) 2.8.

Comment: Daniel, você mencionou explicitamente a versão 2.8 do Scala. Porém a melhor maneira de "Formatar" Strings em Scala veio com interpolação na versão 2.10. Para quem estiver interessado: [link para a documentação](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa usar números para indicar posição. Por padrão, a posição do argumento é simplesmente a ordem em que ela aparece na string.

Veja um exemplo de como usar isso:

```
String result = String.format("O método format é %s!", "legal");
// resultado igual a "O método format é legal!".
```

Você sempre vai usar um `%` seguido de algum outro caracter para que o método saiba como mostrar a string. `%s` é normalmente o mais comum, e significa que o argumento deve ser tratado como string.

Alguns exemplos para dar uma ideia:

```
// podemos especificar o # de decimais para um número de ponto flutuante:
String result = String.format("10 / 3 = %.2f", 10.0 / 3.0);
// "10 / 3 = 3.33"

// separador de milhar:
result = String.format("O elefante pesa %,d gramas.", 1000000);
// result now equals  "O elefante pesa 1,000,000 gramas."
```

`String.format` usa um `java.util.Formatter`. Para a documentação completa, veja [Formatter javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: Quebrando a cabeça vendo um tutorial, agora que percebi que pra gente é virgula e não ponto rs, vlw cara